# adding items from array to action bar spinner

Tags: android, android-actionbar

my android application gives an error after selecting the navigation item. it fail to add items from array to spinner. my spinner is on the action bar. can someone please assist ?

below is the method that fails, other staff works except hymn_num_spin.setAdapter(dataAdapter1);  line  :

```
        //adding items to the spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (getActionBar().getThemedContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Array_Hym_number);
        dataAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        //displaying all array items(Array_Hym_number) on the spinner(hymn_num_spin)
        hymn_num_spin.setAdapter(dataAdapter1); //
```

main_activity code:

```
public class main_activity extends Activity {
    //Declaration
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayoutview;
    private ListView ListView_navDrawer;
    public ArrayList Array_Hym_number;
    public ArrayList Array_fillHymVerses;
    private ArrayList HymnLanglist;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggleListener;
    public static final String DB_NAME = "yourdbsqlite3.db";
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    public Spinner hymn_num_spinner;
    public Spinner hymn_num_spin;
    private TextView Display_Hymn;
    private String TABLE_NAME="English";
    public TextView Dsp_verse;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity);

        drawerLayoutview = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_Layout);
        ListView_navDrawer = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_listview);
        hymn_num_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.action_spinner);
        hymn_num_spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.hymno_spinner);
        Dsp_verse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Dsp_verses);
        //Display_Hymn=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Display_song);
        //Our key helper
        ExternalDbOpenHelper dbOpenHelper = new ExternalDbOpenHelper(this, DB_NAME);
        database = dbOpenHelper.openDataBase();

        //populate Hymn laugages from array
        final List<String> HymnLanglist = new ArrayList<String>();
        HymnLanglist.add("English");
        HymnLanglist.add("Venda");
        HymnLanglist.add("Zulu");
        HymnLanglist.add("Tsonga");
        HymnLanglist.add("Sotho");

        hymn_num_spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new HymnNumberOnItemSelectedListener());

        final ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, HymnLanglist);
        ListView_navDrawer.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        ListView_navDrawer.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), HymnLanglist.get(position) + " Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                drawerLayoutview.closeDrawer(ListView_navDrawer);//this method will close navigation drawer when the item is selected
                setTitle(HymnLanglist.get(position)); //this method will change the title to selected item on listview

                TABLE_NAME = HymnLanglist.get(position);//Set the table name before calling fillHymNumber() method
                fillHymNumber();

            }

        });
        //navigation drawer open and closed behaviour
        drawerToggleListener = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayoutview, R.drawable.drawerbar, R.string.Open_drawer, R.string.Closed_drawer) {
            public void onDrawerOpened(View DrawerView) {
                hymn_num_spin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Dsp_verse.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                super.onDrawerOpened(DrawerView);

                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Drawer Opened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            public void onDrawerClosed(View DrawerView) {

                super.onDrawerClosed(DrawerView);
                hymn_num_spin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Dsp_verse.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Drawer Closed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
        drawerLayoutview.setDrawerListener(drawerToggleListener);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);//make action bar icon/title clickable
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);// Enabling Up / Back navigation
    }

 private void fillHymNumber() {
        TABLE_NAME="English"
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), TABLE_NAME + " Table Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Array_Hym_number = new ArrayList<String>();
        //reading data from the database
        Cursor friendCursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{"hymn_org_no",
                "hymn_new_no"}, null, null, null, null, "hymn_new_no");
        friendCursor.moveToFirst();
        if (!friendCursor.isAfterLast()) {
            do {
                //adding only hymn_new_no on the array
                Array_Hym_number.add(friendCursor.getString(1));
            } while (friendCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        friendCursor.close();
        //adding items to the spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (getActionBar().getThemedContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Array_Hym_number);
        dataAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        //displaying all array items(Array_Hym_number) on the spinner(hymn_num_spin)
        hymn_num_spin.setAdapter(dataAdapter1);
    }
```

activity_main_activity code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/action_spinner"
        android:entries="@array/Array_entries"


        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

i was trying to add the spinner from android layout which i managed to get the spinner displayed on action bar but it did not allow me to add items during runtime from the array.Android comes with buld in spinner item no need to add it from layout. the only thing required is to enable it using ActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_LIST) then after that you need to set ListNavigationCallbacks and OnNavigationItem selected. after that i managed to add items during runtime from the array